# "burnt/burned out" vs. "frazzled" to describe a person

Tags: meaning

What are the differences in connotation and meaning between these two?

> A. She is burned/burnt out from all of this work.
>
> B. She is frazzled from all of this work.

Does one have a more negative connotation than the other? Does "frazzled" have a stronger sense of "disheveled" to it? Does "burnt out" imply a sense of permanence or severity?

Which would you rather be called, between the two? Does one offend or insult more than the other?

Comment: They are often synonymous. When they differ, _frazzled_ more likely refers to the short term, whereas _burned out_ is more often a long-term consequence.

Comment: I think of frazzled as "coming apart", not able to hold things together, whereas burnt[burned] out means just tired of it all, not caring anymore what might happen and ready to give up, but not necessarily at wit's end.

Answer (score 5):

If you are **burned out** then it is implied that you have a longstanding issue that is causing you to have apathy.  There is a connotation of a pretty long history of conflict or issues causing the burned out person to under perform.  People are often burned out by doing repetitive tasks.

If you are **frazzled** then that means that something about a particular situation caused you to be (usually mentally) exhausted.  It is assumed that a person cannot think straight while they are frazzled.  Something is invoking them to shut down.  This could last for just a moment to some short-term period.

I personally don't see the words as interchangeable.  They have distinctly different meanings.

Usage: "I have been working at this factory for 5 years, doing the same thing every day.  I am so burned out."

Usage: "When I went to meet with my boss about my raise, his hot secretary was in the meeting with us.  I was so frazzled that I didn't even bring the raise up."

So you can see just from the examples that burned out has more of a negative meaning while I think frazzled can really go either way.  Burned out can be compared to being worn down and frazzled can just be really nervous, out of it, or just not able to think because of emotions.  You could be frazzled around someone because of hatred but that is just one of many reasons the term could be used.

[Being nervous is Merriam-Webster's focus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frazzle) on frazzled and on burned out it is [overworked or overused](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burned+out?show=0&t=1379049409).

Comment: I know you're good, and I'm not saying you are wrong but you are only giving the OP (and myself) your interpretation of these two terms. The examples you give are your own. I could just as well give my interpretations of these expressions and fit my examples around them. Could you provide any source?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - My head doesn't count?

Comment: Of course it does, but did you not read my comment? The best answers on ELU usually (not always) have some form of documented evidence unless the person has built such a reputable reputation that no one dares to contradict him or her! :) Otherwise, IMO, sources are a way of saying to readers: Here's the proof. "It's not just my opinion". It also makes for a better argued answer and gives future visitors references they can choose to either look up or ignore.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't disagree with you but I tend to skip all of those long, boring, sourced quotes.  I couldn't live with myself if I bored you.

Comment: A link is more than enough :) Sometimes an answer just requires an opinion, but here you are saying burned out and frazzled are distinct whereas I thought they were quite similar to each other. And the idea of being so frazzled (by someone's beauty?) so that you cannot think straight is new to me. Maybe it's a recent development, maybe it's true only in the US. I don't know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I left you intrigued because it wasn't formed from a source!  Maybe it is just American.  I will get you an example.

Comment: @Ryebread, thank you for this answer. I wonder if there is some more subtlety attached to this in common usage, however. For example, at the end of a long day with children at Disneyland, would you say that you are burned out or that you are frazzled? My instinct is that in casual usage, it could be either. What do you think? In this case the sense of "nervous" ascribed to "frazzled" doesn't really seem to apply...

Comment: @sammy - Well you would normally say frazzled there because it was just one day - burned out would be a little bit of an exaggeration.  The fact is that frazzled has a few meaning.  The most common one now is nervousness (not able to think) but as I mentioned in the answer it can mean exhausted too.  In the Disneyland example the person is probably both physcially and mentally exhausted or spent.  Burned out wouldn't work unless you said - after 5 days straight of going to Disneyland, I am a little burned out.

Answer (score 1):

Burnout is a feeling of being overworked and is a generally accepted definition for overworking which can include symptoms such as:

- Feeling tired and drained most of the time
- Lowered immunity, feeling sick a lot
- Frequent headaches, back pain, muscle aches
- Change in appetite or sleep habits

(More can be found [here](http://www.helpguide.org/mental/burnout_signs_symptoms.htm) if you are truly interested)

Whereas *frazzled* is a synonym for stress. Stress is a pre-cursor to burnout as is explained in the article.

Comment: The *literal* definition?  A candle is *literally* burned out.  A person only figuratively.